# i am missing a call for measureoverride function in carousel

Tags: carousel, c++-cx

I've tried to translate the [c#](/questions/tagged/c%23) version of the [carousel](/questions/tagged/carousel) in [c++-cx](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b-cx) one but I am blocked.

Nothing appears, many things have been set in comment but it still doesn't work, I am missing a `measureoverride` call in [c#](/questions/tagged/c%23)

It is 2 `measureoverride` then 2 `ArrangeOverride` and again 1 `measureoverride` 1 `ArrangeOverride`, but in [c++-cx](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b-cx) it is only 2 `measureoverride` then 2 `ArrangeOverride`

Any idea? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you show your codes ?

Comment: hello in fact i found the answer, thanks anyway